# HelloAccessory Samsung Sample App not connecting (Provider and Consumer)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

How can I connect the provider app to the consumer app? I successfully connected it using Samsung S4 and Tizen emulator. But now Im using the S4 and the Gear 2 itself. I ran the app using eclipse and the wgt installed using the gear manager.

> js/main.js (44) :err [undefined] msg[undefined]
>   js/main.js (124) :exception [TypeError] msg['null' is not an object (evaluating 'SASocket.setDataReceiveListener')]
>   js/main.js (44) :err [undefined] msg[undefined]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some error in the main.js.
From what I see in the HelloAccessoryProvider this seems to be the issue.
console.log("exception [" + err.name + "] msg[" + err.message + "]");

Somewhere you are either missing a quote that is making the string 'msg' being treated like a variable.